# Comparing an entire row from one excel sheet to another

Tags: excel, row

Is there a formula that I can use to compare rows (that are not in the same row number) in 2 different sheets?

E.g. I would like to check if the highlighted row in image 1 matches any row in the entire array in image 2. 
[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2SUH.png)
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCpf0.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the smartest method but this is what I would do: create a new sheet, equal two cells and it will give you "True" if the cells equal to each other. then check if every cell in the row equal to "True" by =COUNTA(B1:L1)=COUNTIF(B1:L1,"True") the front/end of the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simple excel formula : equal

```
=Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A6
```

it will write TRUE or FALSE.

You can mix that with an IF statement, returning 0 = TRUE and 1 = FALSE

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A6,0,1)
```

Then you can SUM your line to know if everything is TRUE ! Sum should be 0.

-Séb